# Server Alias is inactive when trying to save through program

Tags: macos, mac, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm recently having a lot of problems since I upgraded from lion to mountain lion when trying to save a file to our local file server through Photoshop or Illustrator.

Before I did the upgrade, I could just select my server alias and it would allow me to view my server content and to save my file on the server.

Now my server alias is inactive and it doesn't show me the content anymore. When I'm trying to save the file on the server through my direct server path (without using the alias) going through Network -> Domain -> Server, I see all the content but it still gives me an error message when I'm trying to save.

Now the weird thing is, I have to mirrored systems where I both did the upgrade. Now on the first one I'm not able to save a file on the server through Photoshop but it works through Illustrator and it's exactly the vice versa behavior on the second system.

I'm always registered and logged in with the server so I guess it has nothing to do with this.

Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

Greyed out alias:

[image: Greyed out alias]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally reached a solution through deactivating preview pictures both on Finder and Photoshop as several articles on the www were guessing that these things don't work too good together.

You can deactivate this function in photoshop by clicking on Photoshop in the upper left part -> Presetting -> Filehandling -> Preview Pictures: Never

In finder going to Viewsettings-> and untick the box.

You may need to adjust the way to find these options, as I'm working on a german system it's quite hard to translate.